# SKAdNetwork : still need third party sdk to measure FB or Google campaigns performance?

Tags: ios, facebook, admob, firebase-admob, skadnetwork

I'm running facebook and Google ads campaigns, and I wonder if I still need to include their sdk to measure those campaigns performance when using SKAdNetwork

According to Apple, with SKAdNetwork, the advertised app’s responsibilities is only to "Provide app install validation information by calling registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution()"
see here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork or here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork/configuring_the_participating_apps

But :

- Facebook says that 2 SKAdNetworkIdentifiers should be added in the app plist, and it is not clear to me whether the facebook sdk is required or not when you run a facebook campaign https://developers.facebook.com/docs/SKAdNetwork
- In the same way, Google lists the required SKAdNetworkIdentifiers and says the "Google Mobile Ads SDK" is required.

All I want to do is to get installs reported in my facebook campaigns dashboard and Google Ads campaigns dashboard, to know my cpi. Does it mean I only have to call registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution() from this app? (and not add any sdk, any SKAdNetworkIdentifier or whatever... really that simple?)

Will Facebook and Google get the installations reported anonymously "magically" ?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: facebook sdk is NOT required , you only have to call registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution ; As far as my knowledge goes, you need some Google sdk (probably firebase or admob) to report installations to Google

Answer (score 2):

SKAdNetwork API is used by 2 clients:

1. App A - source app (the application that present ads)
2. App B - advertised app’s

The SDKs that you mentioned are considered as AdNetworks,
If you are only advertising your app (App B) than you should only call the following SKAdNetwork API methods:

1. registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution
2. updateConversionValue

**Will Facebook and Google get the installations reported anonymously "magically" ?**

Because AdNetwork SDKs are implemented in the source app (App A), apple will know from which AdNetwork your app install came from, see - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork/signing_and_providing_ads?language=objc.

When the end-user will open your app, after registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution() function is called apple will fire the adNetworkAttribution postback to the correct AdNetwork/*

**Apple documentation:**

The source app’s responsibilities are to:
Add the ad network’s ID to its Info.plist. See Configuring the Participating Apps.
Display ads that the ad network signs. See Signing and Providing Ads.

The advertised app’s responsibilities are to:
Provide app install validation information by calling registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution or updateConversionValue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but I just had the same doubt about Facebook SDK - Am I supposed to call registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution inside my app?

Searching on Google, I've found that the Facebook SDK should already call this API by itself, so no code should be required inside our apps!

Source: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/AppEvents/FBSDKAppEvents.m#L1313